# presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to display my popover menu whenever the user clicks on a button.

I have two methods, the first creates the button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Forms List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showPopover:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnMenu;

}
```

And the second is called by the first, to display the popover

```
-(IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"called with %@", sender);
    self.popoverController = popoverController;
    popoverController.delegate = self;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

Presently, when I click the button nothing happens.  I think the problem lies in the second method, mainly the `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem` line.

Any help would be appreciated, I don't really understand how that method call works.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Here is the code where I (think) initialize the popoverController

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize toolbar, popoverController, detailItem, detailDescriptionLabel;
```

Comment: Show the code where you create the popover controller. The code you've shown so far looks good.

Comment: This line: `self.popoverController = popoverController;` has nothing to do with your problem, but looks like something being done incorrectly. Presumably you have an interface variable `popoverController` along with a same-named property; the property should be associated with the interface variable in a `@synthesize` statement, and then you would (usually) only reference `self.popoverController` everywhere else in your code.

Comment: i edited it in.  I first declared the popoverController in the .m, then I set the property and synthesize in the .h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you initialized your `UIPopoverController`?

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:VCTHATGOESINSIDE];
```

If all else fails, try presenting it from rect and specify a `CGRect`. Hope this helps!

edit: initWith**Content**ViewController

Comment: sorry for my dumbness, but what would the VCTHATGOESINSIDE be?

Comment: I should've explained better, my bad. `UIPopoverController` needs to be initialized with a ContentViewController (`UIViewController`), which is what you want to display inside that popover rectangle.

Comment: So (if you take a look at the edit I made in the OP), my declaration of *popoverController is incomplete then ?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be initialized as in my answer. I'll give you an example.  `aTableViewController *myTable = [[aTableViewController alloc] init];  UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myTable];`

Comment: ahhhhhh ok.  I have a table view controller on the go already, which is what I am trying to display.  Thanks, your example made it clear!